# Dictionary function with BST returns vector

Tags: c++, windows

The function `dictionary_select` returns a vector which contains words that are starting with W.
In this code `dictionary_select` gives an error message. But I can not find it. Is there anybody can help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct tree {
    string data;
    tree *left;
    tree *right;        
};
typedef tree* dictionary;

bool dictionary_ins_word(dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
    if(W == "" || W == " ")
        return false;

    tree* dic;
    dic = new tree;
    dic->data = W;
    dic->left = NULL;
    dic->right = NULL; 
    if(D == NULL) {
         D = dic;     
    }
    else {
        if(W <= D->data)
            dictionary_ins_word(D->left, W);
        else
            dictionary_ins_word(D->right, W);
    }
    return true;
}
bool dictionary_lookup(const dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
    if(W == "" || W == " ")
        return false;
    if(D == NULL)
        return false;
    if(W == D->data)
        return true;
    else if (W < D->data)
        return dictionary_lookup(D->left, W);
    else
        return dictionary_lookup(D->right, W);
}
bool dictionary_is_empty(const dictionary & D)
{
    if(D == NULL)  
        return true; 
    else
        return false;
}
bool dictionary_del_word(dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
    if(!dictionary_lookup(D, W))
        return false;
    if(W < D->data)
        dictionary_del_word(D->left, W);
    else if(W > D->data)
        dictionary_del_word(D->right, W);
    else {
        string item; 
        tree* temp;
        temp = D;
        if(D->left == NULL) {
            D = D->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if(D->right == NULL) {
            D = D->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else {
            while(D->left->right != NULL) 
                D->left = D->left->right;
            item = D->left->data;

            D->data = item;
            dictionary_del_word(D->left, W);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
bool dictionary_min(string & W, const dictionary & D)
{
    dictionary min;

    if(D == NULL)
        return false;
    min = D;
    while(min->left != NULL)
        min = min->left;
    W = min->data;
    return true;     
}
vector <string> dictionary_select(const dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
vector < string > result;
    vector < string > zeroVec;
    string temp;
    zeroVec.push_back("");

    if(D == NULL)
        return zeroVec;
    temp = D->data;    
    size_t found = temp.find(W);
    if(found == 0)
        result.push_back(D->data);
    if(W <= D->data)
        return dictionary_select(D->left, W);
    else
        return dictionary_select(D->right, W);
}

int main()
{
    bool b[5];
    dictionary l;
    string W, str;
    vector <string> vec;

    l = new tree;
    l->data = "berdi";
    l->left = NULL;
    l->right = NULL;
    b[0] = dictionary_ins_word(l, "atas");
    b[1] = dictionary_ins_word(l, "cara");
    b[2] = dictionary_ins_word(l, "ata");
    b[3] = dictionary_ins_word(l, "atax");
    vec = dictionary_select(l, "ata");
    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        cout << vec[i] << " ";        
    }
    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your function dictionary_select declares the result vector and never returns it.  Below is how you would change this:

```
vector <string> dictionary_select(const dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
    vector < string > result;
    vector < string > tempVector; // add this to store the result from the recursion
    vector < string > zeroVec;
    string temp;
    zeroVec.push_back("");

    if(D == NULL)
        return zeroVec;
    temp = D->data;    
    size_t found = temp.find(W);
    if(found == 0)
        result.push_back(D->data);

    if(W <= D->data)
        tempVector = dictionary_select(D->left, W); // get the recursion result
    else
        tempVector = dictionary_select(D->right, W);  // get the recursion result

    result.insert(result.end(), tempVector.begin(), tempVector.end()); // append all the results
    return result; // return the result
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order for the function to return the correct data, you have to also ensure that you look at both left and right sides of the tree to get the appropriate results. The function below has the update:

```
vector <string> dictionary_select(const dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
    vector < string > result;
    vector < string > tempVectorLeft; // add this to store the result from the left recursion
    vector < string > tempVectorRight; // add this to store the result from the right recursion
    vector < string > zeroVec;
    string temp;
    zeroVec.push_back("");

    if(D == NULL)
        return zeroVec;
    temp = D->data;    
    size_t found = temp.find(W);
    if(found == 0)
        result.push_back(D->data);

    if(found == 0 || W <= D->data)
        tempVectorLeft = dictionary_select(D->left, W);  // store results

    if(found == 0 || W > D->data)
        tempVectorRight = dictionary_select(D->right, W);  // store results

    result.insert(result.end(), tempVectorLeft.begin(), tempVectorLeft.end()); // append all the left results
    result.insert(result.end(), tempVectorRight.begin(), tempVectorRight.end()); // append all the right results
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @ivash: Result vector contains just two words even there are more

Comment: Your search seemed to look for words that start with keyword "found == 0" is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to return a vector of all strings starts with string W

Comment: so what is the value of string W for the second test?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following variant:

```
vector <string> dictionary_select(const dictionary & D, const string & W)
{
    vector < string > result;
    vector < string > zeroVec;

    if (D == NULL)
        return zeroVec;
    string temp = D->data;
    size_t found = temp.find(W);
    if (found == 0)
        result.push_back(D->data);
    if (found || W <= D->data)
        for(auto x: dictionary_select(D->left, W))
            result.push_back(x);
    if (found || W > D->data)
        for (auto x : dictionary_select(D->right, W))
            result.push_back(x);
    return result;
}
```

The problem in the `if` / `else`  approach used in you initial algortihm to choose between recureion on left or right node, is that you could have a note like this:

```
       atar
       /  \
     ata  atax
```

So if the data in the head of the node matches, you need to check both left and right to be sure that you're not missing something.

Comment: @ivash: Thanks but gives error :expected primary-expression before "auto"; expected ';' before auto

Comment: @ivash: Could you say me what is x here?

Comment: `auto x` defines a loop variable which will take the type contained by the container following the `:`. As `dictionary_select()` returns a `vector<string>`, `x` will be a `string`.  More about range-for : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for